# What do you call a relation that isn't finer than any equivalence, besides the full relation?

Tags: logic, terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

In other words, this is a relation whose "equivalence closure" is the full relation. The term "weakly connected" comes to mind naturally, since if you draw a directed graph, with a vertex coming from $x$ to $y$ if and only if $xRy$, then this graph will indeed be weakly connected.

But some sources reserve the term "weakly connected" for relations for which $\forall_x \forall_y xRy \lor y Rx$ holds. From graph-theoretic standpoint, the best name for such relations would be "weakly full", but that's beside the point really.

So, is there a standard solution to this in literature? If not, what can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you do mean when you say "a relation whose "equivalence closure" is the full relation". Do you mean a relation $R$ such that its symmetric and reflexive-transitive closure $\overline{R}$ is: $x\overline{R} y$ for all $x, y$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Disclaimer:* The following is more a non-answer than an answer. I hope someone else can contribute with more insightful ideas.]

We are talking about a binary relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ over some set $X$ such that its equivalence closure $=_R$ (the symmetric and reflexive-transitive closure of $R$, i.e., the intersection of all the equivalence relations on $X$ containing $R$) is the universal (or trivial) relation, that is, $x =_R y$ for all $x,y \in X$ ($=_R$ coincide with $X \times X$).

As far as I know, there is *no standard terminology* for such a kind of relation $R$. I checked on Wikipedia's pages about [binary relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) (which contains a glossary their properties) and [generated equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Generating_equivalence_relations), as well as in Schmidt's *[Relational Mathematics](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/relational-mathematics?format=HB&isbn=9780521762687)* (a quite encyclopedic textbook about relations), without finding any name.

*My proposals:* I would say that such a $R$ *generates a universal* (or *trivial*) *equivalence*.  If you look for an adjective, I would say that $R$ is *coarse* or *coarse-grained*, because the equivalence that it generates is the [coarsest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Comparing_equivalence_relations) equivalence containing $R$. But it depends on the context whether this terminology is appropriate or not.
Another proposal is to say that $R$ is (*weakly*) *connecting*, because if you represents $R$ as a directed graph (with $X$ as the set of vertices), you get a [(weakly) connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Directed_graph_connectivity) graph.

In my opinion, it is misleading to use *connex* or *connected* because

- it is quite standard to use connex for a relation $R$ such that $xRy$ or $yRx$ for all $x,y \in X$;
- it is well established that *connected* refers to (directed) graphs, and the pair $(R,X)$ can be see as a directed graph, but here you are looking for an adjective for $R$ only.

I would not use *complete*, *full* or similar either, because this kind of terms is overloaded (think of order theory or graph theory), with different meanings. It is true that if you represent $=_R$ as a graph, then you get a complete graph, but this is a property of $=_R$, not of $R$.